# Set column collate in NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, collation

I'm looking into NHibernate mapping and we are in a situation where we require to specify the collate on a specific column. Preferably during the mapping.

The idea is that after NHibernate creates the schema, it will look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] (
    [Bar]        NVARCHAR (128) NULL **collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as**,
    [BarTwo]     NVARCHAR (max)
);
```

I'm currently using Fluent but an xml solution would be fine as well.

Comment: as a workaround could you try `.Default("collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as")`?

Comment: Sorry, this does not work. However I found a solution by using `.CustomSqlType("nvarchar(128) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS")`. However it means that I need to use the sql type and cannot rely on the Length property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that I can add the collate to the CustomSqlType.
It does mean that I need to add always a CustomSqlType and therefore make the mapping database depended.

```
.CustomSqlType("nvarchar(128) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS")
```

But for now it seems to work. 
Anyone has another/better idea/proposition?